# filter out multiple rows based on the content of one element in a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with many rows that are all repeated values except for the values in column `dd`.

If any one row contains the value "ACT" in this non-repeated column I need to remove all the rows which otherwise match this "ACT" row as well as the "ACT" row itself.  So in the sample code I would want to retain only the six rows which contain "c" and "e" in column `aa`.

I have tried a variety of nested if-else with for loops and trying to somehow filter out based on value in `aa` when the "ACT" exist in `dd` but have not been able to figure out how to get away from the single row vector matching.

```
aa <- c("b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e")
bb <- c("t","t","t","w","w","w","r","r","r","s","s","s")
cc <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
dd <- c("CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR")
```

Ideally I'm look for a `tidyverse` solution but am open to anything of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(
  aa = c("b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"),
  bb = c("t","t","t","w","w","w","r","r","r","s","s","s"),
  cc = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  dd = c("CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR")
)

anti_join(df1, df1[df1$dd=="ACT", ], by=c("aa","bb","cc"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   aa    bb       cc dd   
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 c     w         2 CVR  
#> 2 c     w         2 CVR  
#> 3 c     w         2 CVR  
#> 4 e     s         4 CVR  
#> 5 e     s         4 CVR  
#> 6 e     s         4 CVR
```

- Using `data.table` package:

```r
library(data.table)
df2 <- data.table(
  aa = c("b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"),
  bb = c("t","t","t","w","w","w","r","r","r","s","s","s"),
  cc = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  dd = c("CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR")
)

df2[!df2[dd=="ACT",], on = c("aa","bb","bb")]
#>    aa bb cc  dd
#> 1:  c  w  2 CVR
#> 2:  c  w  2 CVR
#> 3:  c  w  2 CVR
#> 4:  e  s  4 CVR
#> 5:  e  s  4 CVR
#> 6:  e  s  4 CVR
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can put the vectors in a data.table and keep only the (aa, bb, cc) groups which don't have "ACT" in the dd column.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(
  aa = c("b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"),
  bb = c("t","t","t","w","w","w","r","r","r","s","s","s"),
  cc = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  dd = c("CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","ACT","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR","CVR")
)

df[, if(!"ACT" %in% dd) .SD, .(aa, bb, cc)]
#    aa bb cc  dd
# 1:  c  w  2 CVR
# 2:  c  w  2 CVR
# 3:  c  w  2 CVR
# 4:  e  s  4 CVR
# 5:  e  s  4 CVR
# 6:  e  s  4 CVR
```